# Order by with grouping on 2nd column

Tags: sql, sql-server

Been trying to solve this but without success.

Here's my table

```
SN      PID
----    ---------
1       NULL
2       1000005
3       NULL
4       1000002
5       1000005
6       NULL
7       1000002
8       NULL
9       1000005
```

I need the sorting to be by SN but when PID is not null, it needs to group them together.  Hence the result i'm looking for is

```
SN      PID
----    ---------
1       NULL
2       1000005
5       1000005    -- group together with the previous SAME PID
9       1000005    -- continue to group together
3       NULL       -- continue to the next unused SN (no more PID = 1000005)
4       1000002
7       1000002    -- group together with the previous SAME PID
6       NULL       -- continue to the next unused SN
8       NULL
```

Appreciate anyone's advice.  Thanks!

Comment: Why are the NULL values not together?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would solve this by sorting with an artificial column that is equal to the MIN `SN` of all the rows with the same `PID`, or equal to the `SN` when `PID` is null.

```
SELECT *,
 CASE 
   WHEN PID IS NULL THEN SN
   ELSE (SELECT MIN(t2.SN) FROM MyTable t2 WHERE t2.PID=t1.PID)
 END AS sortby
FROM MyTable t1
ORDER BY sortby, SN
```

If you need to exclude `sortby` in the output, you can either use the above as a CTE, or you can plug the CASE expression directly into the ORDER BY and leave it out of the SELECT list.

Comment: If you use `MIN` with an `OVER` clause you could put this in a CTE and bin the subquery (and second scan of the table).

Comment: Yes there are a few different ways to write this, using the same basic principle.   I felt that a subquery was the most illustrative example, though not the most performant.

Comment: I used CTE to eliminate that extra SortBy column.  Works like a charm!

Answer (score 1):

I would use window functions:

```
select sn, pid
from (select t.*,
             dense_rank() over (order by pid desc) as seqnum_pid,
             row_number() over (partition by pid order by sn) as seqnum_null
      from t
     ) t
order by (case when pid is null then seqnum_null else seqnum_pid end),
         (case when pid is null then 1 else 2 end);
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=b666da09aefae5746813c7c01dc2960d) is a db<>fiddle.

Or, you can use window functions in the `order by`:

```
select sn, pid
from t
order by (case when pid is null then sn else min(sn) over (partition by pid) end)
```